# Error on declaring current date (vb for office)

Tags: exception, datetime, vba, timestamp

the code of my my form is this:

```
Dim dtmTest As Date

dtmTest = DateValue(Now)
```

and the error is: external procedure not valid.
it highlights the word now

Comment: how to reply to a comment here? so, in response to @Tony dallimore sure it must be that. I'm based in a spanish speaking country. but the entire program is written in english, the way i like it. </br> No reserved names were used in this program.

Comment: What happens if you type `?Now()` into the immediate window? Are any references marked MISSING (code window, Tools->References)?

Comment: You might also try `?vba.now()`

Comment: it sets the word Print in blue instead of the question mark.  then the word Now. parentheses are kept this time. but when opening the form, it returns the same error. same for `vba.now`. </br> wait, did I understand correctly?

Comment: I do not think so, choose in the code window View->Immediate window or ctrl+G and type the question mark commands into that.

Comment: kudos to you, and excellent news: the only command that passed the test was `?vba.now()` because `vba.ahora()` goes all [Member not found Error 461] and the other two return same old error. sad news come: assigning `vba.now()` to variable dtmTest returns that warning as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:
`dtmTest = Date()`

Or, for date and time use:

`dtmTest = Now()`

Comment: @Remou-- Feeling incredibly dumb here: what does "chr chr" mean?

Comment: It means I was not interested in adding to my comment, but I had hit the minimum for Stackoverflow comments, chr = character, a space filler :)

Comment: I hope this answer works but on my system `dtmTest = DateValue(Now)` does not give an error.  If `DateValue(Now)` gives an error on the `Now`, why should calling it directly help?  Where is agaragaragar based?  Is this a version problems because `Now` has a different name on his system?

Comment: Tony Dallimore Wouldn't the external procedure be DateValue in agaragaragar's example? I wonder if a library is missing or if the name has been used by accident in a procedure.

Comment: @Remou.  The compilation would work in calculation sequence: `Now` then `DateValue`.  Maybe if it had got past `Now` it would have failed on `DateValue`.  It could be a library problem.  It thinks `Now` is an external procedure rather than an undefined variable so I cannot see that it could be caused by a variable named `Now`.  I know that some functions have different names in different countries but know no more.  I threw that in as a possibility but have no idea if it is a sensible suggestion.

Comment: @Tony `Now` is one of the functions that die in an unexpected way when an unrelated library is missing.

Comment: it returns the same old window, with the same old error. in addition, it removes the parentheses. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

From the above, it seems that have a missing or broken reference. Look at the references (code window, tools->references) and check if any are marked missing, if there is one, untick it and look for a suitable matching reference. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283806)

It is generally best to use late binding in production, because the libraries for the various Office products, such as Excel, frequently reference, vary from PC to PC.

If you do not find a missing reference, you can try to delete the VBA library itself - it will not let you, but for some reason, this seems to help.

Comment: I tried deleting it by unticking the box next to the line with the text "VBA for applications" in Tools > References. But no change in the actual outcome.  For some reason turning my definition to the actual main form from the second one seems to get the job done. There must be a mistake somewhere when calling the second form.

Comment: I got a similar thing going on now with another variable, this VBA environment is vastly queer.

Comment: Can you decompile? It often fixes weirdness. http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm, after that, there is a short list of other things. Try decompile, first, though.